# ERROR when trying to insert date values into new table (ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected )

Tags: oracle, syntax-error

I am trying to insert values into my table but I keep getting error

```
ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
```

This is my code:

```
INSERT INTO PRODUCT_DIM_HIS
(PRODUCTKEY, PRODUCTID, PRODUCTDESCRIPTION, PRODUCTLINEID, PRODUCTLINENAME, EFF_START_DATE, EFF_END_DATE)
SELECT PRODUCT_KEY_SEQ.NEXTVAL, nvl(to_char(p.PRODUCTID), 'Undefined'), nvl(to_char(p.PRODUCTDESCRIPTION), 'Undefined'),
nvl(to_char(p.PRODUCTLINEID), 'Undefined'), nvl(to_char(pl.PRODUCTLINENAME), 'Undefined'), 
nvl(to_date(o.ORDERDATE), 'Undefined'), nvl(to_date(o.FULFILLMENTDATE), 'Undefined')
FROM PRODUCTLINE_T pl, PRODUCT_T p, ORDER_T o, ORDERLINE_T ol
WHERE p.PRODUCTLINEID = pl.PRODUCTLINEID
AND o.ORDERID = ol.ORDERID 
AND ol.PRODUCTID = p.PRODUCTID;
```

PRODUCT_DIM_HIS CODE *Requested*:

```
CREATE TABLE PRODUCT_DIM_HIS
(
    PRODUCTKEY integer NOT NULL,
    PRODUCTID integer,
    PRODUCTDESCRIPTION VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
    PRODUCTLINEID integer,
    PRODUCTLINENAME VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
    EFF_START_DATE DATE,
    EFF_END_DATE DATE,
    CONSTRAINT PRODUCT_DIM_HIS_PK PRIMARY KEY (PRODUCTKEY)
);
```

ORDERDATE and FULLFILlMENTDATE from ORDER_T have DATE datatypes so I don't understand what the problem is?

@BOB_JARVIS

```
CREATE TABLE PRODUCT_DIM
(
    PRODUCTKEY integer NOT NULL,
    PRODUCTID integer,
    PRODUCTDESCRIPTION VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
    PRODUCTLINEID integer,
    PRODUCTLINENAME VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
    CONSTRAINT PRODUCT_DIM_PK PRIMARY KEY (PRODUCTKEY)
);

INSERT INTO PRODUCT_DIM
(PRODUCTKEY, PRODUCTID, PRODUCTDESCRIPTION, PRODUCTLINEID, PRODUCTLINENAME)
SELECT PRODUCT_KEY_SEQ.NEXTVAL, nvl(to_char(p.PRODUCTID), 'Undefined'), nvl(to_char(p.PRODUCTDESCRIPTION), 'Undefined'),
nvl(to_char(p.PRODUCTLINEID), 'Undefined'), nvl(to_char(pl.PRODUCTLINENAME), 'Undefined')
FROM PRODUCTLINE_T pl, PRODUCT_T p
WHERE p.PRODUCTLINEID = pl.PRODUCTLINEID;

INSERT INTO PRODUCT_DIM
(PRODUCTKEY, PRODUCTID, PRODUCTDESCRIPTION, PRODUCTLINEID, PRODUCTLINENAME)
VALUES (PRODUCT_KEY_SEQ.NEXTVAL, -99, 'Undefined', -99, 'Undefined');
```

Comment: What's the data type of the other fields on PRODUCT_DIM_HIS?

Comment: I would hazard a guess that one of the dates is null, and being substituted with 'Undefined' through `nvl()`.  This type of error is very easy to debug.  Just expose the value you're actually trying to send to the database.

Comment: @BobJarvis I have added it above

Comment: @Khyron I dont get what you mean, I put nvl so that the null values would convert to 'undefined'

Comment: @pyuntae `'undefined'` is a string literal, not a keyword.  Oracle will not be able to convert the string 'undefined' to a date, and in fact the error is telling you exactly that.  Refer to the `nvl()` documentation.  It would be able to if it looked enough like a date.  Eg. '2017-11-29'.  Instead of using `'undefined'` as the null substitution, try a hard-coded date.

Comment: @Khyron I deleted the NVL() and did just o.ORDERDATE and o.ORDERFULFILLMENT but I still get the same error.

Comment: I got it, I just needed to keep the to_date() part...

Comment: So, `fulfillmentdate` is `DATE` data type. In your code you wrap this within `to_date()`. What do you think that does? If you are not sure, use your friend Google to read the documentation for `to_date()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove NVL() and just leave to_date():

Therefore,

```
INSERT INTO PRODUCT_DIM_HIS
(PRODUCTKEY, PRODUCTID, PRODUCTDESCRIPTION, PRODUCTLINEID, PRODUCTLINENAME, EFF_START_DATE, EFF_END_DATE)
SELECT PRODUCT_KEY_SEQ.NEXTVAL, nvl(to_char(p.PRODUCTID), 'Undefined'), nvl(to_char(p.PRODUCTDESCRIPTION), 'Undefined'),
nvl(to_char(p.PRODUCTLINEID), 'Undefined'), nvl(to_char(pl.PRODUCTLINENAME), 'Undefined'), 
to_date(o.ORDERDATE), to_date(o.FULFILLMENTDATE)
FROM PRODUCTLINE_T pl, PRODUCT_T p, ORDER_T o, ORDERLINE_T ol
WHERE p.PRODUCTLINEID = pl.PRODUCTLINEID
AND o.ORDERID = ol.ORDERID 
AND ol.PRODUCTID = p.PRODUCTID;
```